# Understanding the concept of hereditary sets

Tags: set-theory

I have just started set theory and I am having one big issue with understanding what a pure/hereditary set is.

The definition I had is that a set is pure/hereditary if the elements of such set is also a pure/hereditary set.

The way I understand this definition is that a pure set is a set such that its element is also a set.

Then I was thinking, is $\{1\}$ a pure set? Clearly the only element is just $1$ and I do not think $1$ on its own is a set and thus $\{1\}$ is not a pure set?

Could someone please give me several examples of pure sets and not pure sets so that I could better my understanding!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a hereditary (or pure) set is a set whose elements are all *hereditary* sets. Thus, a set that is not hereditary has some element that is not hereditary. This means that the empty set is vacuously hereditary: it has no elements, so it certainly has no elements that are not hereditary sets. From this we can construct the set $\{\varnothing\}$, the set whose only element is the empty set. Since the only element of $\{\varnothing\}$ is hereditary, $\{\varnothing\}$ is itself hereditary.

In the usual von Neumann construction of the ordinal numbers, $1$ is defined to be $\{\varnothing\}$, so $\{1\}$ is indeed hereditary: its only element is $1=\{\varnothing\}$, which, as we just saw, is hereditary.

If one works in $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ set theory, the only objects are sets, so **all** sets are hereditary. There are, however, axiomatizations of set theory that allow [objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement), called *atom* or *urelements*, that are **not** sets but can be elements of sets. It is in those versions of set theory that the distinction between hereditary sets and non-hereditary sets comes into play.

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight. I have two questions if you do not mind answering? So am I right in thinking that $\{1\}$ is 'the same as' $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$?

Comment: @JustWandering: You’re very welcome. Yes, in the usual formal development of set theory each ordinal number **is** the set of all smaller ordinal numbers, so $0=\varnothing$, $1=\{0\}=\{\varnothing\}$, and therefore $\{1\}=\{\{0\}\}=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$.

Comment: @JustWandering: In this same development $$2=\{0,1\}=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}\,,$$ and $$3=\{0,1,2\}=\left\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}\right\}\,,$$ so $\big\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$ can be reduced to an expression containing only curly braces and $\varnothing$, though one that’s long enough that I’d prefer not to type it out!